# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 Express

Tags: javascript, react-native, express

I am attempting to follow this tutorial (https://levelup.gitconnected.com/introduction-to-express-js-a-node-js-framework-fa3dcbba3a98) to connect Express with React Native via . I have a server.js script running which connects to the client (App.tsx) on my ip, port 3000. The server and app are run simultaneously on the same device in different terminals. The server is able to recieve GET requests just fine, as when the app launches, a useEffect function calls a GET request, and the server sends a message. However my POST requests, which contain a content body set to `JSON.stringify("hello world")` are not working. and the server script returns the following error anytime I press the button:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
...
```

I'm assuming I am sending in badly formatted json, or haven't set the content type properly, but I haven't been able to figure out the exact problem.

App.tsx (where myip is my ip address):

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://myip:3000/get")
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(res => console.log(res.theServer))
   }, []);
  

  async function handleSubmit() {
    console.log('button press');
    const response = await fetch("http://myip:3000/wow/post", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify("hello world")
    });
  const body = await response.text();
  setResponse({ responseToPost: body });
  }

  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit}>
     <Text>Submit</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
}
...
});
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get("/get", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ theServer: "hElLo FrOm YoUr ExPrEsS sErVeR" });
});
app.post("/wow/post", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(`Here is what you sent me: ${req.body.post}`);
});
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: Is the error that gets thrown inside body-parser? Random idea, if body-parser isn't needed as an additional middleware, perhaps Express is trying to parse the JSON twice, and thus you just need to remove this line? `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: why do you think the req.body has a `post` property? you're not sending one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you no longer need to explicitly include `body-parser`. It is now bundled with Express and available via the following functions...

```js
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded()) // extended = true is the default
```

---

The JSON parsing middleware is configured to handle objects by default. While a string literal like `"hello world"` is valid JSON, it's not what the framework expects, hence your error.

Since you appear to be trying to access `req.body.post`, you should send your data with such a structure

```js
fetch("http://myip:3000/wow/post", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ post: "hello world" })
})
```

Alternatively, if you did want to post a JSON string literal, you would need to configure your JSON middleware like so

```js
app.use(express.json({ strict: false }))
```

> `strict`
>
> Enables or disables only accepting arrays and objects; when disabled will accept anything `JSON.parse` accepts.

in which case your `"hello world"` string would appear in `req.body`

Comment: It is kind of _crazy_ that you have to do extra paramter configuration to have express.json() middleware accept the full json specification (which includes blank strings, numbers, ... But thank you, app.use(express.json({ strict: false })), did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

for me, adding

```
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

solved the problem